# How to read an IIS 6 Website's Directory Structure using WMI?

Tags: c#, web, iis-6, wmi, directory

**I need to read a website's folders** using WMI and C# in IIS 6.0. I am able to read the Virtual directories and applications using the "IISWebVirtualDirSetting" class. However the ***physical folders located inside a website cannot be read using this class.***

**And for my case i need to read sub folders located within a website** and later on set permission on them. For my requirement i dont need to work on Virtual Directories/Web Service Applications (which can be easily obtained using the code below..).

I have tried to use IISWebDirectory class but it has been useful.

Here is the code that reads IIS Virtual Directories...

```
public static ArrayList RetrieveVirtualDirList(String ServerName, String WebsiteName)
{
    ConnectionOptions options = SetUpAuthorization();
    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\MicrosoftIISV2", ServerName), options);
    scope.Connect();
    String SiteId = GetSiteIDFromSiteName(ServerName, WebsiteName);
    ObjectQuery OQuery = new ObjectQuery(@"SELECT * FROM IISWebVirtualDirSetting");
    //ObjectQuery OQuery = new ObjectQuery(@"SELECT * FROM IIsSetting");

    ManagementObjectSearcher WebSiteFinder = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, OQuery);
    ArrayList WebSiteListArray = new ArrayList();
    ManagementObjectCollection WebSitesCollection = WebSiteFinder.Get();
    String WebSiteName = String.Empty;
    foreach (ManagementObject WebSite in WebSitesCollection)
    {
        WebSiteName = WebSite.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString();
        WebsiteName = WebSiteName.Replace("W3SVC/", "");
        String extrctedSiteId = WebsiteName.Substring(0, WebsiteName.IndexOf('/'));
        String temp = WebsiteName.Substring(0, WebsiteName.IndexOf('/') + 1);
        String VirtualDirName = WebsiteName.Substring(temp.Length);
        WebsiteName = WebsiteName.Replace(SiteId, "");
        if (extrctedSiteId.Equals(SiteId))
        //if (true)
        {
            WebSiteListArray.Add(VirtualDirName );
            //WebSiteListArray.Add(WebSiteName);
            //+ "|" + WebSite.Properties["Path"].Value.ToString()
        }
    }
    return WebSiteListArray;
}
```

**P.S:**

I need to programmatically get the sub folders of an already deployed site(s) using WMI and C# in an ASP. Net Application. I need to find out the sub folders of existing websites in a local or remote IIS 6.0 Web Server. So i require a programmatic solution. Precisely if i am pointed at the right class (like IISWebVirtualDirSetting etc ) that i may use for retrieving the list of physical folders within a website then it will be quite helpful.

I am not working in Powershell and i don't really need a solution that involves powershell or vbscripts.

Any alternative programmatic way of doing the same in C#/ASP.Net will also be highly appreciated.

EDIT:

### GetSiteIdFromSiteName

The code may look like this:

```
public static int GetSiteIdFromSiteName(String ServerName, String WebsiteName)
{
    ConnectionOptions options = SetUpAuthorization();
    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\MicrosoftIISV2", ServerName), options);
    scope.Connect();
    ObjectQuery OQuery = new ObjectQuery(@"SELECT * FROM IIsSetting");

    ManagementObjectSearcher WebSiteFinder = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, OQuery);
    ArrayList WebSiteListArray = new ArrayList();
    ManagementObjectCollection WebSitesCollection = WebSiteFinder.Get();
    String WebSiteName = String.Empty;
    foreach (ManagementObject WebSite in WebSitesCollection)
    {
        WebSiteName = WebSite.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString();
        WebsiteName = WebSiteName.Replace("W3SVC/", "");
        String extrctedSiteId = WebsiteName.Substring(0, WebsiteName.IndexOf('/'));
        break;  
    }
    return extrctedSiteId;
}
```

and

### SetupAuthorization()

Here is the SetupAuthorization function.

```
    public ConnectionOptions SetUpAuthorization()
{ 
        ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
    //options.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Connect; 
    //may need to set Packetprivacy enum
    options.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy; 
    options.EnablePrivileges = true; 
    options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate; 

     return options;
 }
```

Regards

Comment: Which version of .NET are you targeting?

Comment: @Steve: BTW, you should not be using `ArrayList` unless you're stuck at .NET 1.1. Use `List<string>` instead.

Comment: I am targetting at v2.0 of .Net Framework. But does it have any relation with the problem i am facing?

Comment: The above code is just a sample of similr things that i am doing and for the sake of clarity of purpose. I have been successful in retrieving the list of virtual directories and i am now aiming at retrieving the list of actual sub folders located in the physical path of the website.

Like if the website is in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\, i need to find all sub folders in this directory path...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind. i got it myself.
If the directory structure is on local system the System.IO.DirectoryInfo is what is needed. Using remoting the same can be used for remote server as well.

**Reference:**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx

If WMi has to be there then Win32_Directory is the class which should used in query:

```
"Select * from Win32_directory where drive ='"+ DriveLetter +":' and Path ='%" + MyPath + "%'";
```

**Reference:** 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394130(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at the Web Deployment Tool?

http://www.iis.net/expand/WebDeploy

Ability to package ACLs, COM, GAC and registry settings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I wonder how this tool is gonna help me or asist me in some way.???

I need to programmatically get the sub folders of an already deployed site(s) using WMI and C# in an ASP. Net Application. I need to find out the sub folders of existing websites in a local or remote IIS 6.0 Web Server. 

I don't think that am doing any thing that has something to do with this web deployment tool. 

So if you would kindly enlighten me...plz...