# Get a list of sites running under IIS on a remote server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, iis-6

I have a page running under IIS 6.0 on server Foo. I have some other sites also running under IIS 6.0 on a remote server Baz. I want to ping Baz with Foo with ASP.NET to retrieve a list of sites running on it. How can I do this?

Possibly like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962725/get-list-of-apppools-from-iis), except in C# instead of VB.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10248365/is-microsoft-web-administration-dll-redistributable) tells me that using Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll is not really an option because it's not distributable and only available on IIS 7.

Comment: does this work : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521247/how-to-read-an-iis-6-websites-directory-structure-using-wmi

Answer (score 4):

Here's a code snippet to get a list of running Web Sites using Microsoft.Web.Administration, this DLL is located here : c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string serverName = "localhost";
            using (Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager sm = Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.OpenRemote(serverName))
            {
                int counter = 1;
                foreach (var site in sm.Sites)
                {
                    Console.Write(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Site number {0} : {1}{2}", counter.ToString(), site.Name, Environment.NewLine));
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Replace "locahost" with the remote server name.

Hope this works for IIS 6 (i tried it with IIS 7.5 only ;-))

Comment: While trying to do this, I was missing the dll. In fact, my entire \System32\inetsrv\ folder is empty. What should I do about this?

Comment: @Sho do you have IIS installed on the machine you are writing the code on? If not get the DLL from a machine that is running IIS.

Comment: Ah I see. The server that has IIS does not have the file as well, so I'm assuming it's not something in IIS 6, only in 7.

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager(v=vs.90).aspx, the class is for IIS 7

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can achieve this with `System.DirectoryServices`

```
        string path = "IIS://{yourservername}/W3SVC";

        using (DirectoryEntry w3svc = new DirectoryEntry(path))
        {
            foreach (DirectoryEntry entry in w3svc.Children)
            {
                if (entry.SchemaClassName == "IIsWebServer")
                {
                    string websiteName = (string)entry.Properties["ServerComment"].Value;
                }
            }
        }
```

Make sure you've enabled remote IIS administration on Baz

Comment: Now would I be able to 'enable remote IIS administration' without having to log onto each box individually? I might have 100+ Baz boxes when I deploy this.

Comment: Have you tried the code? It seems remote administration doesn't need to be enabled unlike IIS7.

Comment: I tried it but all of the values under DirectoryEntry w3svc have thrown unknown exceptions of type System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException